# How to undo drawing in paintComponent in Java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw, paintcomponent

Hello im making a simple web broswer and im using Java Graphics library to render the html elements,
by printing some 2D graphics on a JPanel (HTML Canvas) using the paintComponent methond
but the problem is each time I call my web page method (print on the jpanel) all the components are printed underneath what has been printed already, (let's say I change the url and load a differed web page it gets printed on underneath the previous one) but I want the HTML Canvas to be cleared every time before it gets printed on, I almost tried everything I found on the web nothing helped my case, please help me.

```
public class HtmlCanvas extends JPanel  {

    private boolean drawLineMark;
    private int lineMarkX;

    private List<HtmlComponent> htmlComponents;


    public void setHtmlComponents(List<HtmlComponent> htmlComponents) {
        this.htmlComponents = htmlComponents;
        drawLineMark = false;
        lineMarkX = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        // Turn on font aliasing (smoothing)
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
           RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
            if (htmlComponents != null)
                drawHtmlComponents(g);
            if (drawLineMark)
                drawLineMark(g, lineMarkX);
        }

    }

 
    private void drawHtmlComponents(Graphics g) {

        int xLoc = X_MARGIN;
        int yLoc = Y_MARGIN;

        try {
            for (HtmlComponent component : htmlComponents) {
                g.setColor(component.getColor());
                if (component instanceof HtmlTag) {
                    xLoc = Y_MARGIN;
                    drawTag(g, (HtmlTag) component, yLoc);
                    yLoc += component.getHtmlComponentHeight();
                } else if (component instanceof HtmlFragment) {
                    drawFragment(g, (HtmlFragment) component, xLoc, yLoc);
                    xLoc += component.getHtmlComponentWidth();
                } else if (component instanceof HtmlLabel) {
                    drawLabel(g, (HtmlLabel) component, xLoc, yLoc);
                }
                else if (component instanceof HtmlLink) {
                    drawLink(g, (HtmlLink) component, xLoc, yLoc);
                }

            }
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ignored) {
        }
    }


    private void drawFragment(Graphics g, HtmlFragment htmlFragment, int xLoc, int yLoc) {
      
    }... other drawing functions.



}
```

Comment: So pairing in Swing is like painting on a canvas in real life, you can't "undo" what has been done so much as you can paint over it.  This means you should be clearing the graphics context each time `paintComponent` is called.  This is actually the default operation of `paintComponent`, assuming the component is transparent.  So, since you seem to be doing that and you don't seem to be caching the graphics context between repaints, this means that there is something else going on which we can't see because you've not provided a [mcve]

Comment: Don't do `setBackground(Color.WHITE);` in `paintComponent`.  Set that when you create the `JPanel`.  Your `super.paintComponent(g)` call will take care of painting the background.

Comment: *List<HtmlComponent> htmlComponents;* - clear the List before adding new components to it in your application code.

Comment: *"making a simple web broswer"* A `JEditorPane` is a 'simple' web browser. It required a lot more work than I warrant a single person could handle, and it still sucks. Pursue an existing solution (e.g. The Java-FX based `WebView` embeds an **actual** web browser into an app).